# Detect session expires to restore stocks if the user adds a product to the cart but never checks out

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I have created an online shop with a `products` table. In each row there is column called `stock`, so when a user adds a product to the cart that has `stock=5`, the stock in the database is set to `4`.

The doubt: if the user adds a product to the cart, but he/she never goes to checkout and he/she just let the browser open for a long time.., how to to restore the stock?

Since I have set the lifetime cookie to 1 hour, I would like to restore stocks if the user has added some product to the cart and let inactive the browser for more than one hour.

I looking for PHP (or a safe Javascript client-side) solution.

I'm using symfony as PHP framework.

Comment: You can use localstorage, which is used to store the values inside the browser with no expiration limit. Once stock got checkout you can clear the localstorage item. For eg, localStorage.setItem("stock", "Product");
localStorage.getItem("stock"); localStorage.removeItem("stock");

Comment: A possible quick-fix would be to update `stock` in database after the user actually _completes_ checkout. Downside is possible overselling if the store gets very high traffic.

Comment: Apart from @Iskar suggested, I would also store the "potential orders" in DB in a separate table, so you could erase those records when they expire and add the `stock` back to original table...

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to handle stock overflow with shopping carts, though I would advise against putting the user session or client-side implementation in control of stock. From a data perspective, you want your product data to always reflect the actual stock that you have in the store.

One rather simple solution is to use a `cart` table with a design like:

- User ID
- Product ID
- Quantity
- Date/Time Added

When somebody adds something to a shopping cart, instead of updating the `products` table, you would insert a row in this new `cart` table. You might also refresh the "date/time added" field when they perform other interactions with their cart.

Whenever you need to make a stock check, you can take the value of `products.stock` for the item and subtract the value of any stock that is currently in the `cart` table, for example with a query like this (using MySQL as an example):

```sql
SELECT products.stock - SUM(cart.quantity) 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN cart ON products.id = cart.product_id 
WHERE products.product_id = 123 
GROUP BY products.product_id;
```

Then you would regularly sweep this table for expired products. This could be done with a cron task, or it could be better implemented as a Symfony event that is dispatched any time a stock check is requested.

**This is how a Symfony solution would look:**

Suppose in your controller you have a check for the stock value, which access a service method that performs something like the query above:

```
$stock = $this->get('your_stock_service')->calculateStock($product);
```

Instead, you could dispatch this event first:

```
use Example\Event\StockEvent;
use Example\Event\StockEvents;

// ...

$this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(StockEvents::STOCK_CHECK, new StockEvent($product));

$stock = $this->get('your_stock_service')->calculateStock($product);
```

Your actual event name would be defined in `Example\Event\StockEvents.php` (to follow Symfony convention):

```
<?php

namespace Example\Event;

final class StockEvents
{
    /**
     * An event that is dispatched prior to stock being checked for a product.
     */
    const STOCK_CHECK = 'stock.stock_check';
}
```

To define this `StockEvent` you could make a simple class in `Example\Event\Stock.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Example\Event;

use Example\Entity\Product;

class StockEvent
{
    /**
     * @var Product
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     */
    public function __construct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    /**
     * Get the product.
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }
```

Separately you would design an event listener, let's say `StockEventListener`:

```
<?php

namespace Example\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Example\Event\StockEvent;

class StockEventListener
{
    /**
     * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @param Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * Remove any temporary stock from carts after one hour.
     *
     * @param StockEvent $stockEvent
     */
    public function clearTemporaryStock(StockEvent $stockEvent)
    {
        // use a cutoff of one hour
        $cutoff = new \DateTime();
        $cutoff->sub(new \DateInterval('1 hour'));

        $queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();

        $queryBuilder
           ->delete('Example\Entity\Cart', 'c')
           ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->lt('c.date_added', ':cutoff'))
           ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('c.product', ':product'))
           ->setParameter('cutoff', $cutoff)
           ->setParameter('product', $stockEvent->getProduct())
           ->getQuery()
           ->execute();
    }
}
```

And then finally you would hook it up via `services.yml`:

```
example.listener.stock_listener:
    class: Example\EventListener\StockEventListener
    arguments: [ '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager' ]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: stock.stock_check, method: clearTemporaryStock, priority: 1 }
```

With all of this in place, each time you check the stock of a product, the controller will first dispatch the event and the above listener will be executed, clearing any stale values from the table.

A final note is that this still may not be a great solution for a complex store, because a large percentage of shopping carts drop off and you would lose sales as a result. It really becomes a question of user experience: are you okay with rejecting a checkout because somebody else has *just* purchased a product, or would you prefer to lock products in this manner and tell the user "you have an hour to check out with this product" or something similar.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your answer, I don't know if it is 100% correct but I think is really inspiring!